# android: Reading of LogCat doesn't work without PC connection

Tags: android, android-logcat

I am really puzzled by bahaviour of my app. When I have my mobile connected to eclipse and my service is reading every line of logcat in order to looking for substring - everything is OK. Immediately when I disconnect my mobile from PC, "logcat reading code" doesn't work.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));                       

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.indexOf("some string") > 0)...
```

I download some logcat apps and they are able to show exactly the same logCat lines as ... eclipse. Can you help me please?

Comment: Well, LogCat shows you otuput from your device or emulator. So when you disconnect it - it stops reading... I mean you can't even run android app without device or emulator being connected. Or didn't I understand you?

Comment: My app is on mobile and I can see without PC if my service(which is still working without connection of course) found substring in LogCat. Code is on mobile => so when I disconnect mobile - it doesn't stop reading - logcat still exists.

Comment: All right, started to make sense for me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I lost 5 hours of my life. It look's like when logfile is exported to PC, android add there some additional information(e.g time + tag...) which are not originally included. I had there second condition if (line.length()>= 120) which was true if mobile was connected with PC (line was longer because of additional inf.) and was false when mobile wasn't connected!!!

Problem was that it is not possible to find this bug by debuging :(

Answer (score 1):

You don't say anything and maybe you do it. But, have you added the permission **android.permission.READ_LOGS** in Manifest?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"></uses-permission>`

Comment: Thank for idea, but yes I have this permission. It is working well - but only when is the mobile connected with PC.

Comment: Ok, I've been testing in my Nexus S and I can see the logcat using that code, sorry but I can 't help you...

Comment: I have done the same and... down is my solution. Thank you very much for your time.